# Installed mac OSX 10.8 "mountain lion" and I have a rectangle around my mouse arrow

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

I've just upgraded to Mountain Lion and everything seems to work apart from an annoying black rectangle always around my pointer.

Here a screenshot (you can't see the pointer):
[image]

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Fixed:

System preferences > Accessibility > Zoom > More Option > deselect "Show preview rectangle"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please keep in mind to come back and mark your answer as the accepted solution. Thanks :)